# Facing problems setting up breadcrumbs in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am trying to solve a breadcrumbs related problem since morning but still cannot get hold on it. I am using Angular 10 and trying to make use of angular routing to get breadcrumbs working on the top of every page for my application. Here is my problem and the code:

**The problem:**
I have enabled lazy-loading in the application and currently the breadcrumbs seems to be working only partially as only one breadcrumb is getting shown for every component where I navigate to.

e.g. When I navigate from Library to books component as per code below, I should see `'Library -> Book Foo'` and `'Library -> Book Bar'` respectively as breadcrumbs.

But I am only seeing single links like `'Book Foo'` and `'Book Bar'` when I navigate to any of such relevant component.

**Directory Structure**

```
app
  app.component.ts
  app.component.html
  app.component.scss
  app-routing.module.ts
    |
    |
    |
library
  LibraryComponent.component.ts
  LibraryComponent.component.html
  library-routing.module.ts
    |
    |
    |    
books
  BookFoo
    BookFooComponent.component.ts
    BookFooComponent.component.html
    BookFooComponent.component.scss
  BookBar
    BookBarComponent.component.ts
    BookBarComponent.component.html
    BookBarComponent.component.scss
  books.module.ts
```

**books.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'book-foo', 
    component: BookFooComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb:'Book Foo'
    }
  },

  { path: 'book-bar', 
    component: BookBarComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb:'Book Bar'
    }
  },

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BookFooComponent,
    BookBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    _SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class BooksModule { }
```

**library-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: NestedroutingComponent,
    children:[
      { path: 'library', 
        component: LibraryComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Library'
        }, 
      },
      { path: 'books', loadChildren: () => import('../books/books.module').then(m => m.BooksModule) }
    ] 
  }
];
```

**bread-crumb.service.ts** (I have followed this from one of the SO answer located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61949211/3047069))

```
@Injectable()
export class BreadcrumbService {
  
  breadcrumbChanged = new EventEmitter<IBreadCrumb[]>(false)

  private breadcrumbs: IBreadCrumb[] = []

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((routeEvent) => { this.onRouteEvent(routeEvent) })
  }

  onRouteEvent(routeEvent: Event) {
    if (!(routeEvent instanceof NavigationEnd)) { return }

    // Get the parent route snapshot
    let route = this.router.routerState.root.snapshot
    let url = ''

    const newCrumbs = []

    while (route.firstChild != null) {
      route = route.firstChild

      if (route.routeConfig === null) { continue }
      if (!route.routeConfig.path) { continue }

      url += `/${this.createUrl(route)}`

      // check until the routes contains title defined in it
      if (!route.data['breadcrumb']) { continue }

      const newCrumb = this.createBreadcrumb(route, url)
      newCrumbs.push(newCrumb)
    }

    // reassign breadcrumb list with new breadcrumb list
    this.breadcrumbs = newCrumbs
    this.breadcrumbChanged.emit(this.breadcrumbs)
  }

  createBreadcrumb(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, url: string): IBreadCrumb {
    return {
      displayName: route.data['breadcrumb'],
      url: url,
      route: route.routeConfig
    }
  }

  createUrl(route: any) {
    return route && route.url.map(function (s) { return s.toString() }).join('/')
  }
}
```

**breadcrumbComponent.component.ts** (this component fetches breadcrumbs based on service listed above)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-shared-breadcrumbs',
  templateUrl: './shared-breadcrumbs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shared-breadcrumbs.component.scss']
})

export class SharedBreadcrumbsComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  breadcrumbs: IBreadCrumb[];

  constructor(private breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService) {
    this.breadcrumbService.breadcrumbChanged.subscribe((crumbs: IBreadCrumb[]) => {
      this.onBreadcrumbChange(crumbs)
    })
  }

  private onBreadcrumbChange(crumbs: IBreadCrumb[]) {
    this.breadcrumbs = crumbs
  }
}
```

**breadcrumbComponent.component.html** (template to show breadcrumbs on all pages)

```
<nav>
  <ol style="padding: 0%; display: flex;">              
    <li *ngFor="let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a [routerLink]="[breadcrumb.url]">{{ breadcrumb.displayName }}</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

**What I tried ?**

I feel like I have exhausted all my options, first I tried to change my lazy-loading structure to modify it to contain some child components, but everything is getting messed up. I tried reading about lazy-loading much more into detail but I found very less information on dynamic breadcrumbs.

At first I had tried [this](https://dev.to/zhiyueyi/create-a-simple-breadcrumb-in-angular-ag5) tutorial but faced same problems, and it also navigates to all wrong paths upon clicking. At this point I am pretty sure that I will have to change some of my routes so that parent, child relationship is followed, but don't know where to start.

Would be really glad if someone can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: It would be very helpful to create a StackBlitz demo based on this problem. In the meanwhile, you could try to add the `path: 'books'` route as a child of `path: 'library'` route

Answer (score 0):

**Another** aproach to get a breadcrumb -yes, I know that is not scalable- is that the "data" was an array (I say "another" because this answer has nothing about the code you post)

```
{ path: 'book-foo', 
    component: BookFooComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb:[{link:'../',text:'Library'},{text:'Book Foo'}]
    }
  },
```

Then, only need

```html
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <ol >
        <li *ngFor="let bread of breadcrumbs|async;let last=last" [ngClass]="{'active':last}">
          <ng-container *ngIf="!last">
             <a routerLink="{{bread.link}}">{{bread.text}}</a>
             <span class="arrow right"></span>
          </ng-container>
          <span *ngIf="last">{{bread.text}}</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
```

```
export class BreadCrumsComponent{
    breadcrumbs = this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(map(res => res.breadcrumbs))
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

}
```

Well, I use an array of object with link,text, is possible make it only with text.

Comment: Sorry for late replies, but i recently fixed this problem by making use of `<xng-breadcrumb></xng-breadcrumb>` from xng-breadcrumb package and also defining routes in component module as mentioned above in `books.module.ts`

Comment: @Dhruvify could you pls create stackblitz? am also facing issue to set up complex breadcrumbs. I've so many feature modules in app.. so need to show in detail. Trying to achieve like `Menu > Users List>View User>XYZ`